# IOS kingfisher ImagePrefetcher - increase of memory use when scrolling tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, memory-leaks, kingfisher

I have a tableview filled with images. I use kingfisher to get the images from urls and I use an ImagePrefetcher because I need to preload my images so that the user can scroll the tableview and see its images even if he loses his Internet connection.

Memory use increases when the tableview is scrolled. My issue is that this memory use isn't released when the controller is dismissed.

I read that [the ImagePrefetcher can be the cause of this memory leak](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/issues/594). What should I do to avoid the leak?

Thank you,

Alex